# Is it possible (and if so how) to delete a zookeeper node with apache camel?

Tags: apache-camel, apache-zookeeper

I am looking into using Zookeeper to synchronized distributed Camel instances. In doing so it seems that there is not possibility to delete a znode from Zookeeper from Camel (I imagined some sort of producer operation).

A look at the components source seems to confirm this. (I didn't find any code explicitely requesting a node removal).

Am I missing something ? When would a node created via Camel (in my case EPHEMERAL) be deleted ? Maybe I am miss understanding something with zookeeper ?

Answer (score 1):

No this is currently not possible. I have logged a ticket to add such functionality in a future Camel release: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-5843

Comment: Noted. I've created an adapted version of the component by adding a CamelZookeeperOperation header (à la camel-cache) which does a delete instead of a write to the ZookeeperProducer class. Would you like me to submit it ? If so how should I proceed ?

Comment: Ok, rather than creating a new jira, I added the patch to the one you created ;)